# geolocation.watchPosition breaks geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm working on a web app with google maps and using `getCurrentPosition()` to get the user position. That works fine but I need to track user position over time.

For this I intended to use `watchPosition()`. Acording to the API reference [API reference](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_error_interface) it must immediatly execute data acquisition and execute the callback, but it doesn't. Instead it freezes, and I can no longer use `getCurrentPosition()`. I have been searching for a cause for this and I cant figure out why is behaving that way. I'm using the latest Chrome for Linux Mint "Lisa".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On a mobile device, `.getCurrentPosition()` is very inaccurate. Using `.watchPosition()` is more accurate, but it takes about five seconds to get the best reading. After that, it wastes battery to keep it active.

This checks the position every 15 seconds using `.watchPosition()` and stops checking after five seconds using `.clearWatch()`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/phabq6r3/

Script:

```js
var latitude, longitude, accuracy;

function setGeolocation() {
    var geolocation = window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( 
        function ( position ) {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
            document.getElementById( 'result' ).innerHTML += 
                  'lat: ' + latitude + ', '
                + 'lng: ' + longitude + ', '
                + 'accuracy: ' + accuracy + '<br />';
        },
        function () { /*error*/ }, {
            maximumAge: 250, 
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        } 
    );

    window.setTimeout( function () {
            window.navigator.geolocation.clearWatch( geolocation ) 
        }, 
        5000 //stop checking after 5 seconds
    );
};

setGeolocation();

window.setInterval( function () {
        setGeolocation();
    }, 
    15000 //check every 15 seconds
);
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This script is completely absurd. watchPosition gets called when the script loads, and a second time after 15 seconds for no reasons. Of course setTimeout does not call setGeolocation every 15 seconds, and you don't have to. The first function given to watchPosition will get a callback if the position of the user actually changes. It's also pointless to call clearWatch after 5 seconds.

Comment: @user414873 `getPosition()` by itself is very inaccurate on a mobile device. If you call it every 15 seconds, every result you get will be inaccurate. `watchPosition()` gets more accurate up to about three attempts (around 5 seconds). After that it's just wasting the battery. `clearWatch()` turns it off until you're ready to track again. This is the best method for tracking on a mobile device.

Comment: jsfiddle broked

Comment: @BraianMellor Thanks.